# Community bulletin can't quite fit "EVENT" on one line

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There's a special EV
EN
T

coming up, according to the Community Bulletin:

[image]

Comment: It's true on Meta, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed, will be live after our next production build

Comment: It looks like a changed was rolled out, but it's still goofy for me (Chrome/Win8) http://i.stack.imgur.com/jIjtp.png

Comment: I'm going to fix it right away

Comment: Eh, @Stéphane - while this is fresh in your mind, it appears that blog posts and meta posts aren't differentiated in the bulletin either.

Comment: I removed the icon, this way it's easier to know the bulletin type.

Comment: i'm sorry, but for me it's still broken. Both on my Windows machine and my windows phone, the T breaks off.