# Insufficient space in the community bulletin layout

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The below image illustrates the problem clearly:

[image: Sample image]

Note how the informative tag *"EVENT"* is wrapped due to insufficient space in the layout.

[The same problem has been addressed before](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/972/community-bulletin-cant-quite-fit-event-on-one-line) on a previous site design, but the issue has arisen again.

Comment: Looks fixed for me. What's your browser?

Comment: Firefox 25.0.1, confirmed as not fixed on this end.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed, will be live after our next production build.